# How to handle back button click in a Dialog in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am showing a custom dialog when there is no internet connectivity. I want to do some handling when the user presses the back button while the dialog is visible.

BackHandler inside the parent screen nor within the dialog itself is working in this scenario.

Thank you

Comment: What version of Compose are you using? `BackHandler` inside a `Dialog` is only supported in [Compose 1.3.0-beta03](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.3.0-beta03) and higher.

Comment: I am using 1.3.2

Comment: And I have tested this even with 1.4.0-alpha03, but still not working.

Comment: Then you'll want to show your code on how you set up your Compose `Dialog` and how you add your `BackHandler` inside that `Dialog` instance as [the test that verifies this behavior](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/ui/ui/src/androidAndroidTest/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/DialogTest.kt;l=269) works every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onDismiss` callback and disable automatic dismissal when the user taps outside the dialog. This way you can ensure that the dismiss request originated from a back press. This is a workaround, of sorts, since an out-of-the-box API is not yet bundled with Compose.

Comment: Yes but that scenario is not working for when using back button click, I had tried that too.

Comment: It works, my bad I was testing on a different dialog. thank you

Comment: Well if it works, you are supposed to accept the answer. Tap on that little check mark icon below the vote counter and it will be marked as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Just define the `BackHandler` function inside the `Dialog`:

```
val shouldShowDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

if (shouldShowDialog.value) {

    Dialog(onDismissRequest = { shouldShowDialog.value = false }) {
        Button(onClick = {shouldShowDialog.value = false}){
            Text("Close")
        }

        BackHandler {
            // your action
        }
    }
}
```